# Expressing conditional statements using quantifiers and predicates in Predicate Logic: how to recognize the hypothesis and conclusion in statement

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I was solving questions of Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications
 By Kenneth H. Rosen Chapter 1 The foundations: Logic and Proofs , when i got stuck at this problem; two similar problems are having different expressions with  predicates and quantifiers

> **35. Express each of these statements using predicates
>   and quantifiers**
>
> *b)* A man qualifies for the marathon if his best previous time is less
>   than 3 hours and a woman qualifies
>   for the marathon if her best previous time is less
>   than 3.5 hours.
>
> > *Solution*: $∀x(((M(x)∧T (x, 3))∨(¬M(x) ∧ T (x, 3.5)))→ Q(x))$,
> >     where $Q(x)$ is “*x* qualifies for the marathon,” $M(x)$ is “*x* is a man,” and $T(x, y)$ is “*x* has run the marathon in less than *y* hours”
>
> *c)* A student must take at least 60 course hours, or at least 45 course hours and write a master's thesis, and receive a grade no lower than a B in all required courses, to receive a master's degree.
>
> > *Solution*: $M →((H (60) ∨ (H(45) ∧ T )) ∧ ∀y G(B, y))$, where $M$ is the
> >     proposition “The student received a masters degree,” $H(x)$ is
> >     “The student took at least $x$ course hours,” $T$ is the proposition
> >     “The student wrote a thesis,” and $G(x, y)$ is “The person got
> >     grade $x$ or higher in course $y$”.

Please help me understand why in first example  "if his best previous time is less
than 3 hours(for man) or if her best previous time is less
than 3.5 hours (for woman)" forms the hypothesis ie p of conditional statement p→ q and in second example "A student must take at least 60 course hours, or
at least 45 course hours and write a master's thesis,
and receive a grade no lower than a B in all
required courses" is not taken as hypothesis p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we translate a statement "$B$ **if** $A$" or, equivalently, "**if** $A$, **then** $B$" as:
$$A\to B$$
which means that *it is never the case that $A$ and $\neg B$*.

Now, your second statement "A student must [conditions] to receive a master's degree" is equivalent to "A student receives a master's degree **only if** [conditions]", meaning that *it is never the case that a student will receive a master's degree and not satisfy [conditions]*. Therefore:
$$\text{master}\to\text{conditions}$$
If we'd written $\text{conditions}\to\text{master}$ instead, then a student could receive a master's degree while not satisfying [conditions], hence breaking the **only if** requirement.

Comment: I am still not clear about using conditionals. There's this another problem: Problem #13 Let M(x, y) be “x has sent y an e-mail message” and T (x, y) be “x has telephoned y,” where the domain consists of all students in your class. Use quantifiers to express each of these statements.  g) There is a student in your class who has sent everyone else in your class an e-mail message.  My solution to it is " ∃x∀y(y = x ∧ M(x, y)) " whereas the book says " ∃x∀y(y = x → M(x, y)) " .

Comment: (The site is displaying 'equal to' symbol instead of 'Not equal to'; Please consider it Not equal to symbol. Sorry for inconvenience). Okay my take on the problem - the conditional statement gives True even with A and B being False and True respectively. Implying  if "x not equal to y" is false ie x is indeed equal to y ie x and y are same person and M(x,y) is true ie x did sent y a message . Then doesn't it violates the condition the question wants to emphasise "who has sent everyone else". Please enlighten.

Comment: @user2114530 You can write logic statements between dollar symbols `$...$`. Use `\exists` for $\exists$, `\forall` for $\forall$, `\to` for $\to$, `\land` for $\land$, `\lor` for $\lor$, `\neg` for $\neg$ and `\neq` for $\neq$.

Comment: @user2114530 Universal statements are always of the form $\forall x(Ax\to Bx)$: everything that is $A$ is also $B$. If we had $\forall x(Ax\land Bx)$: everything is both $A$ and $B$, which is too strong. Hence, your solution means "there is a student $S$ such that every student is not $S$ and $S$ has sent every student an email". But that doesn't make sense: how can $S$ be a student, yet no student is $S$?

Comment: @user2114530 Instead, the correct solution, with the implication, means: "there is a student $S$ such that every other student ($y\neq S$) has received an email from $S$".

Comment: Yeah,  i got it now. Using \land i was ignoring the fact that \land encompasses all the students even the one who is sending everyone an email. On the other hand \to would pick only those students out of the lot that doesn't match the S ie everyone else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23920/discussion-between-mysty-and-demosthene).